# can we use RGB color with Powershell

Tags: powershell, colors

Is there any way to use RGB color in powershell, to add color to some excel fields.

I can only see colorindex and it has only 56 colors. Very limited

Comment: Did you ever get it to work? I'm trying to get some rainbow in my console and it seems confusing and not really intuitively behaving...

Answer (score 1):

You can use RGB color in PoSH. Here is an set of examples.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176944.aspx
If you are a Web designer you might very well find yourself needing to calculate RGB color values. Although Windows PowerShell doesn't include a built-in method or function for calculating RGB values you can write a simple equation that will do the math for you.

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Communary.ConsoleExtensions/1.0.69/Content/Functions%5CWrite-RGB.ps1
This function lets you write to the console using 24-bit color depth.  You can specify colors using its RGB values.

I've not tried to do this with Excel, but you can find note on the web from Excel bloggers who have done similar.
For example:
List Excel Color Values
Lists Microsoft Excel colors and their corresponding integer values. 
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/6c8f0604-ebe1-473a-b35c-31c49890abef